# How to preserve BTEP data when switching from Amazon App Store to Play Store?

Tags: applications, amazon-appstore, titanium-backup

I want to replace as many as possible of the apps that I got though the Amazon Appstore app (AAa) with apps from, say, Google's Play Store.<sup>1</sup>

Of these "Amazon-purveyed apps" the most important one (by a very wide margin) is Better Terminal Emulator Pro (BTEP), which I purchased from the Amazon Appstore many months ago, and have used extensively ever since.

> Is there an easy way to save my current (Amazon) BTEP's data, and restore this data once I have installed a new (non-Amazon) BTEP?

Now, as it happens, I have Titanium backups ("app+data") of all these apps.

> How can I restore the BTEP *data alone* from my BTEP Titanium backup?

(As far as have been able to find, Titanium offers the option of restoring the app alone, or restoring the apps data along with the app, but I have not found any option to restore the data alone.)

Thanks!

<sup>1</sup><sub>Why?  Because the Amazon Appstore app (AAa) I have on my phone *has to go*.  I never use it anymore, and yet it starts on its own, and causes all manner of grief.</sub>

Comment: +1. This is a much broader question, I see BNEP just as an example here. Could you formulate your question more generic so that other user will find it even if they don't search for BNEP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a backup
2. Uninstall the Amazon copy
3. Install BTEP from the Play Store
4. Open Titanium Backup and select your BTEP backup. As long as the app is installed at the time, it will give you the option to restore data only:

[image]